# Why do we inverse figures in their absence for vectors?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

> Two people push horizontally on a box, exerting the forces shown:

[image]
[image]

> $F_1$ :
>
> $x$ component $6 \sin 40^{\circ} = 3.86$
>
> $y$ component $-6 \cos 40^{\circ} = -4.60$
>
> $F_2$ :
>
> $x$ component $-5 \sin 30^{\circ} = -2.50$
>
> $y$ component $5 \cos 30^{\circ} = 4.33$

**Two** questions please:

**1:** Why do we inverse the newtons?

**2:** Why is $F_1$, going south east keeping the $6$ newtons as its $x$ component, but $F_2$, going north east using it's $5$ newtons as its $y$ component? example, Why are they NOT BOTH in the $x$ or the $y$?

Answer (score 1):

1. We don't. Negative is left/down, positive is right/up. Thus, the vector going up and left has positive $y$ component and negative $x$ component, and the vector going down and right has positive $x$ component and negative $y$ component.
2. I have no idea what you mean: both have both an $x$ and a $y$ component, and while their respective magnitudes are used to compute both, neither is equal to the magnitude.

Comment: That's a great explanation! Thank you so much. Just with number 2, sorry for not being so clear, but your first explanation did a great job solving it.  Can I ask please, why do we do +6 and -6, in the absence of coordinates? How would I know that both lines are + and - of the single figures, when it is not a 45 degree angle?

Comment: Broadly, because whoever made the diagram is being lazy. To make the formulae look sensible, they should measure the angles from the positive-$x$ direction. The signs given come from the standard relationships between the sine and cosine of an angle $\theta$ and the sine and cosine of $\theta + 90$.